# How can i grant access to a user for editing registry using c#

Tags: c#

I use the following:

```
        ServiceInstaller ServiceInstallerObj1 = new ServiceInstaller();
        InstallContext Context1 = new InstallContext(string.Format($@"                                                              
                                              {AssemblyDirectory}\myservice.exe"), null);
        ServiceInstallerObj1.Context = Context1;
        ServiceInstallerObj1.ServiceName = "testservice";
        var serviceExists = ServiceController.GetServices().Any(s => s.ServiceName == 
        ServiceInstallerObj1.ServiceName);
        if (serviceExists)
            ServiceInstallerObj1.Uninstall(null);
```

when i go to uninstall it gives the error

***Requested registry access is not allowed and the error
Filename: redirection.config Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions***

I am not running as Admin and not looking at running the app as admin either.

Comment: If the user of your app doesn't have access to something, how is it possible that your program grant them that access?  Doesn't seem like a plausible scenario, unless your app is running under a more privileged identity.

Comment: If i run the app as admin it seems to work , non-admin i get the errors ?

Comment: can i check if i have access to redirection.config , if so i continue , if not display an error ?

Comment: No, you can't do that because it's the framework that is trying to read your config file.  That's one of the first things to happen when your .net application starts - it attempts to load its config file(s).